# Which is the odd one, bananas/meat/vegetables/seafood? Why?

Tags: difference

I cannot find out the odd one from the four items below. Please help me to cross it out and explain why it is different. Thank you.

> bananas / meat / vegetables / seafood

Comment: It's a bad question. Probably "bananas" because that is a specific food, while the other three are categories of foods.

Comment: Almost certainly, I would think - but is this really an English Language question?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not specifically about English.

Comment: It is. it's an exercise in an ESL book, called Topnotch 1.

Comment: What is the exercise about? If you added more detail it would be easier to understand how it relates to learning English. I’m guessing it’s about mass nouns?